# How can I detect the size of a dynamically changing margin with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, margin

In my html I have a div and the div has a random left margin:
Html:

```
<div id=box1></div>
```

javascrpit:

```
$('#box1').css({'margin-left':Math.floor((Math.random()*450)+0)});
```

The problem is that whenever I try to check how big the margin is, like so:

```
document.write($('#box1').css('margin-left'));
```

It always displays 0px, even if the margin is different.
If I try to check with an 'if' statement, I get the same problem.

Comment: works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/r638f6jc/. maybe you should start writing syntactically correct HTML… and don't use `document.write`.

Comment: maybe better to use `window.getComputedStyle` to take care of both inline css and styles applied to element

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `document.write`

```
$('#box1').css({'margin-left':Math.floor((Math.random()*450)+0)});
alert($('#box1').css('margin-left'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3k93zaoq/)

Comment: Well.. instead of displaying the proper value, this moved the div all the way to the left and returned 0px.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, I managed to get it working. The problem was that my document.write was trying to get the value too early. It works if I add a delay like this:

```
setTimeout(show,500); 
function show() {
    document.write($('#box1').css('margin-left'));
};
```

Comment: can't :/ says "can't accpet your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: oops, i am not aware of that kinds of rule.